# "You have an error in your SQL syntax" MySQL ER_PARSE_ERROR 1064

Tags: mysql

This is my code:

```
app.get('/user/:id', function (req, res) {
    let Id = req.params.id;
    console.log(Id);
    connection.query('Select * from user where Id = ?', [Id], function (err, rows) {
        if (err) return console.log(err);

        if (rows.length) {
            console.log('user existed');
            res.send({ message: 'existed' });
        }
        else {
            console.log('not exist')
            res.send({ message: 'not exist' });
        }
    });
})
```

Error:

```
code: 'ER_PARSE_ERROR',
errno: 1064,
sqlMessage: "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1",
```

I don't know what caused the error.

[image]

Comment: Please don't post [images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551) of data, code or errors.

Comment: `user` is a [reserved word in MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/keywords.html), you should surround in with back ticks: `\`user\``.

Answer (score -1):

You may try this. It should work. You have missed the quotation after where **Id**

```
 connection.query('Select * from user where `Id` = ?', [Id], function (err, rows) {
      if (rows.length) {
          console.log('user existed');
          res.send({ message: 'existed' });
      }
      else {
          console.log('not exist')
          res.send({ message: 'not exist' });
      }
});
```

Comment: Removed my comments. By the way: I did not downvote your answer.

Comment: No Problem, already edited the answer :)

Comment: more likely to need backticks around the reserved word `user` :)